# Fixing .android folder facebook sdk mess?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-login

I have pretty serious problem on which I've been stuck for almost 2 weeks. I am not sure where the mistake is so I am planning to deleting everything related to Facebook SDK.

However I am unsure what else is in the .android folder. The contents of it are:

[image: .android folder]

Can I just delete the facebook projects from within the eclipse and clear that folder and start again?

When I was creating the debug key I entered my own password and not "android" so it caused additional problems. I failed to find any help on how to change the password or what to do to generate new one. I tried deleting debug.keystore file, but the problem persists. Any help greatly appreciated.

Lastly does anybody know where I could find some recent [Facebook login tutorials](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/), following the one on Facebook page leads to the following problems:

[image: facebook prob]

The full code for the two classes is as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

public class FBMainFragment extends Fragment{
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));

    return view;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

and:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class FacebookLogIn extends FragmentActivity {

private FBMainFragment mainFragment;
// Your Facebook APP ID
private static String applicationId = "308180782571605"; // Replace your App ID here
private static final String TAG = "FBMainFragment";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new FBMainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (FBMainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.facebook_log_in, menu);
    return true;
}


public static String getTag() {
    return TAG;
}


public static String getApplicationId() {
    return applicationId;
}


public static void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
    FacebookLogIn.applicationId = applicationId;
}

}
```

Comment: You should take care where you put the code from the tutorial. You have put it in `onCreate` instead of `onCreateView`... if you delete the `.android` folder, you are starting over (nearly) like a fresh install of the android sdk... AVDs will be gone but the downloaded apis will still be there...

Comment: Oh right! It seems I have not only put it in the onCreate, but have missed the onCreateView code part. I went through it so many time and still managed to miss it. It seems that deleting the debug.keystore has removed my defined AVDs already. Haven't deleted the whole folder contents yet as I'm not sure  how big implications it will have on the rest of the code in the rest of the projects.

Comment: the folder should not have any impact on your project except the AVD that are stored there.